# Sitecore - Rendering an image with Glass has stopped working, but only on the Web database

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, aero-glass, helix

So I have some components which render images using @Html.Glass().RenderImage. Seemingly overnight the images went from rendering to not. Everything works fine in experience editor which uses the master database but after publishing to the web database and browsing to the site no html is made for the render image call and no image is rendered. Other field types work fine, this is only happening to images.

What I've tried:

- Using a breakpoint in the view and examining what I get in the Glass generated
  model. I receive the correct sitecore item and the correct values for any non-image field, the image field is null.
- Creating different components which use different images: same issue
- rendering the imagefield.raw.url: null exception
- Deleting the items from the web database and republishing: same issue
- Deleting the glass generated code and regenerating: same issue
- Renaming the image field names: same issue
- A coworker even copied my component into his sitecore site (literally copy/pasted everything) and it worked just fine, image and all.

I am unsure what else to try.

This is sitecore mvc.

Comment: I guess you should pick through your configuration and your coworkers to try and work out what's different. And / or set up a clean dev environment yourself and hopefully it'll go away :-/

Comment: Is the *field* published to the web database? Check your template in master vs. web. I had a similar problem with a different field type at one point when I was getting started with `Glass.Mapper`.